# Kineticjs overlapping shapes mouse over detection

Tags: html5-canvas, mouseover, kineticjs

Is there an easy way to do mouse over detection for multiple overlapping shapes in kineticjs (or rapheljs if this is easier in SVG). I.e. if I had two circles that partially overlap, I want to somehow detect the four scenarios:

1) When over no shapes
2) When over circle A
3) When over circle B
4) When over both (the overlap) circle A and B

But I need a generic implementation that could be extended to "n" circles/shapes.

Cheers

Comment: I would like to know this as well.

Answer (score 5):

yep, just use the getIntersections method:

http://www.kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Container.php#getIntersections

this will return all of the KineticJS nodes that intersect a given point (for example the mouse position)

Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! GetIntersections can be used to development my own collision detection... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you're obviously dealing with collision detection. Collision detection algorithms vary depending on the shapes you're checking for detection.

So to start, you could use the lineTo, arc, etc methods and use the built in `isPointInPath` to do the detection, passing in the mouse co-ords. This is the simplest way, especially with odd shaped polygons

```
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(20,50))
    {
        // code
    }
```

Comment: the isPointInPath actually isn't very useful in practice, because it only looks at the previously drawn path.  If your application uses thousands of shapes, the isPointInPath will have to be used immediately after each shape is drawn, which means that you'll have to draw them onto either the visible canvas, or a buffer canvas, thousands of times for each detection request, which creates a huge overhead.  The KineticJS getIntersections() method actually performs hundreds of times faster (measured this) because it uses color map hashing algorithm to determine collision detections